# Problems with truth value gap theory against Strengthened Liar

Tags: philosophy-of-language, paradox

I have been reading Burge's Semantical Paradox, Burge explains how gap theorists have trouble handling the Strengthened Liar, i.e.

> β: β is not true

and there are two things I do not understand:

1. Burge mentions that a gap theorist reply would be to restrict substitutivity of identity to block the move from remarking that the displayed sentence is not true to asserting that β is not true. I assume what he meant is to somehow say 'this sentence is not true' and '"this sentence is not true" is not true' are not the same/salva veritate.

   But then he said,

> This comes to feel more so (ad hoc) when one considers that paradoxes
> can be constructed without using substitutivity of identity, or even
> singular terms

I am having trouble actually naming any paradox that satisfies either of those, does anyone have any idea?

2. Burge argues that this approach does not capture the following intuition.

> Suppose Plato at time T1 says 'What Aristotle says at T1 is not true';
> and Aristotle at time T1 says 'What Plato says at T1 is not true'.
> ...Intuitively, a third party who goes through the
> appropriate reasoning could well say, 'What Plato says at T1 is not
> true' (as well as 'What Aristotle says at T1 is not true') without
> saying anything paradoxical. The third party uses the same singular
> term ('what Plato says at T1') that Aristotle did (and the term could
> obviously be made non-indexical). Paradoxicality does not seem to
> depend purely on what mode of reference is used.

I don't understand what Burge is trying to get at here. What is this 'appropriate reasoning' that allows a third party to escape the paradox? I don't at all see how being a third party makes any difference.

And while I understand how the third party is using the same singular term as Aristotle, I don't see how that entails paradoxicality does not depend 'purely' on mode of reference?

---

[image]

Comment: The Liar Paradox fails because it is not a truth bearer. It has a vacuous object of truth. "This sentence is a box of rocks." can be verified as false because it has a truth object.

Comment: Concerning your first question: Think of the paradox arising from the predicate 'heterological' that applies to all and only the predicates that do not apply to themselves.

Comment: @sequitur Are you referring to the Grelling paradox?

Comment: Buridan's famous paradox assumes perfect symmetry (P's proposition vs A's proposition) and identity of halves, in your case seems to apply from the POV of both P and A since they're basically in a symmetric argument against each other. However, for a third party's POV there's no such locked-in symmetry (as emphasized once by Leibniz), it may very well possible both are wrong...

Comment: @DanielMak Exactly.